# Creating service in angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-services

I want to create a service in Angular to store the userid received from Nodejs.

So I have created a service:

```
MyApp.service('myservice', function(id) {
   var userId = id;
   return userId; 
});
```

And in my controller :

```
MyApp.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $http, myservice){

    $scope.senduser = function(user){

       $http.post("/login", user).then(function(response){
          if(response.data){

            console.log(response.data);
            myservice(response.data.id); //Store the data received from Node to myservice

            } else {
                console.log("No Data");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Im not able to store the data in the service. How do I store the userid in the service to be able to access it later?

Comment: You shouldn't have $http in controller at all. It belongs to a service that needs this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service code can be like this:

```
 MyApp.factory('myservice', function() {
       var userId;

      setUserId = function(id) {
           userId = id;
       }

      getUserId = function() {
         return userId;
      }

    return {
    setUserId : setUserId,
    getUserId : getUserId
    }

    });
```

And in controller you can set and get the value as below :

```
MyApp.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $http, myservice){

$scope.senduser = function(user){

   $http.post("/login", user).then(function(response){
      if(response.data){

        console.log(response.data);
        myservice.setUserId(response.data.id); //Store the data received     from Node to myservice

        } else {
            console.log("No Data");
        }
    });
}
});
```

Comment: First it says `id is not defined`. I defined id as 0. Nothing gets called if i call for myservice.getUserId, it gives `function () {
 return userId;
 }`

Comment: I have edited. Check now.  Also, when you call the getter call it like `myService.getUserId()`

Comment: Thanks. Working now.

Answer (score 0):

The service factory function generates the single object or function that represents the service to the rest of the application.

Change your service code to the one below.

```
MyApp.service('myservice', function() {
    // setting some default value
       this.userId = 0;
});

MyApp.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $http, myservice){

    $scope.senduser = function(user){

    $http.post("/login", user).then(function(response){
      if(response.data){
        console.log(response.data);
        myservice(response.data.id); //Store the data received from Node to myservice
        myservice.userId = response.data.id

        } else {
            console.log("No Data");
         }
       });
    }
 });
```

Comment: Im getting `ReferenceError: id is not defined` for `this.userId = id;`

Comment: Please check it now

Comment: The value doesn't seems to get added to the service. I called it from another controller and it's still 0

Comment: Check this plunkr with the same code, that sets and gets value from service. https://plnkr.co/edit/HEPCnoAe8qrBMgbno2Pc?p=preview , please provide your complete if it still doesn't work